# Uniqueness of vectors, projectors and complimentary projectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, projection-matrices

I'm sort of confused by this statement in a text I'm reading:

> Given a projector $P \in \mathbb{C}^{m \times m}$ define
>   $\text{range}(P) = S_1$ and null$(P)= S_2$. The projector and its
>   complement can be seen as the unique solution to the problem
>
> - Given $v$, find vectors $v_1 \in S_1$ and $v_2 \in S_2$ such that    $v_1 + v_2 = v$      The projection $Pv$ gives $v_1$, and the
>     complementary projection $(I-P)v$ gives $v_2$.
>
> These vectors are unique
>   because all solutions must be of the form
>   $$(Pv + v_3) + ((I-P)v-v_3) = v$$      where it is **clear** that $v_3$ must be in
>   both $S_1$ and $S_2$, i.e., $v_3 = 0$.

To me it appears $v_3$ could be any vector since the form above is simply the addition and subtraction of $v_3$. Why does that form make clear that $v_3$ must be zero? For example let $v_3$ be any nonzero vector then

$$(Pv + v_3) + ((I-P)v-v_3) = Pv + (I-P)v = v_1 + v_2 = v$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}& \underbrace{Pv+v_3}_{\in S_1}+\underbrace{(I-P)v-v_3}_{\in S_2}=v \\
&\implies v_3 \in S_1 \cap S_2 \\
&\implies v_3 = 0 \qquad \qquad \text{since } S_1 \cap S_2 = 0 \text{ for complementary subspaces}\end{align}$$